# Is there such a thing as fractional pixel?

Tags: html, css

I just started helping some work colleagues with some web design. Nothing major, but I have a problem with styled menu elements that are supposed to fill div area allocated and I noticed that whilst I can tweak width settings in ff by adding decimal points in them I noticed that in chromium, the gap between the last styled element and the div border is huge. I Checked the size and realised that chromium is showing the size(S) in rounded integer value. Anyone have any idea as to why this is?

Comment: Different browsers render certain properties/elements in different ways.

Comment: Some kind of subpixel handling is coming: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/117815

Comment: Are you using percentages to determine your sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as *fractional* pixel. Pixel is the smallest screen unit.

The thing you're experiencing happens because of the browsers math engines. Some of them round the decimal pixel part up to the next integer, and some of them floor it down.

To avoid that just define your pixels without decimal points. If you want to make the 2 elements **visually** closer you can play around with colors, for example - if you give a darker border to some elements they will seem to be closer - http://jsfiddle.net/fDbUj/

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was no such thing as a fractional pixel however I was wondering why some browsers allow processed it and why some didn't

Comment: I noticed that when I am using Firebug in Firefox and give padding 10.5px it is bigger than 10px and smaller than 11px. Is the rounding option really working?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul how is that possible if the pixel is the smallest unit on the screen? you can't highlight or darken only a half of it.. are you sure you're using pixels and not points or em-s?

Comment: 100% sure. The `<li>` tags I have are 175px. And they are just a little shy of filling the entire row they are nested in. If I used Firebug to change the padding from 10px to 10.5px they fill the row perfectly. If I change to 11px, the last element flows to a second line. But I have not tried using it outside Firebug.

Comment: OK, I have tested padding: 10.5px and it works for me in IE-10, FireFox-21, Chrome-27. So the above comment with the width of the `<li>` elements - I get the same result if I use width of 176px for the `<li>` and 10px padding or 175px for the `<li>` width and 10.5px for the padding.